# No idea how to convert a signing proivder to .NET 7

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault, .net-7.0

I am converting to .NET 7 and have a signing provider that I didnt write

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;


    public class AzureKeyVaultSigningProvider : ISigningProvider
    {
        private readonly KeyVaultConnectionString _connectionString;

        public AzureKeyVaultSigningProvider(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = new KeyVaultConnectionString(connectionString);
            _connectionString.Validate();
        }

        private KeyVaultClient GetClient()
        {
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(GetTokenAsync);
            return keyVaultClient;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string authority, string resource, string scope)
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

            var clientCred = new ClientCredential(
                _connectionString.ClientId,
                _connectionString.ClientSecret
            );

            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the KeyVault JWT token");
            }

            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        public byte[] SignHash(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var client = GetClient();
            var signedBytes = SignAsync(client, bytes)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
            return signedBytes.Result;
        }

        public async Task<KeyOperationResult> SignAsync(KeyVaultClient client, byte[] bytes)
        {
            KeyOperationResult result;

            if (_connectionString.HasKeyName)
            {
                result = await client.SignAsync(
                    _connectionString.Url,
                    _connectionString.KeyName,
                    _connectionString.KeyVersion,
                    _connectionString.Algorithm,
                    bytes
                );
            }
            else
            {
                result = await client.SignAsync(
                    _connectionString.Url,
                    _connectionString.Algorithm,
                    bytes
                );
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help for how to get this to .NET 7?

I know that KeyVaultClient has been replaced with SecretClient, but there is no valid constructor on SecretClient that takes the equivalent of GetTokenAsync

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, your question is not about "converting to .NET7" but what you are looking for is how to migrate to the latest nuget package `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys`

There is a [full example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys/samples/Sample5_SignVerify.md) for that client on GitHub.